# How can I upload chromedriver when I want to use selenium in aws lambda function?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I want to make python crawler and it works in local.
But I want to run crawler in regularly so I put my crawler in aws lambda.

I downloaded chromedriver and put somewhere in my directory and I can use it in local server.
But in lambda, I don't know how to set the path and upload chromedriver file.

I tried absolute path but it didn't work.
Should I upload the chromedriver for lambda function?
If so, how can I do?

my code in localhost

```
    chrome_driver_path = "../chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path = chrome_driver_path,
        chrome_options=options
    )
    URL = "https://*****.co.kr"
    driver.get(URL)
```

Comment: You can have the driver as part of s3 bucket or else check whether you have any cdn's for chromedrivers located , So that you can refer by the path and use it ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can't run .exe on lambda because it's Linux but you CAN run puppeteer as above and use that to parse the HTML.

Install puppeteer as above(npm i puppeteer --save).
Bundle everything up.(You compress all your code and node_modules into a zip file)
Deploy to AWS.
Voila.

I HIGHLY recommend the Serverless framework as it takes the pain out of deployments, you can get it [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless)

Do bear in mind if your crawling job is going to take more than 15 minutes you'll need to schedule this via cron on something like a t2.micro rather than Lambda because it'll timeout.

Comment: Thank you. It takes more than 15 minutes so I cannot use lambda function anyway. I should find another way as you said.

Comment: So ping me a link to another question, I can help you design that in about 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda cannot run executable files. Have you considered headless chrome?

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.20.0&show=outline

Comment: It can't run EXE files but it can run linux binaries? Perhaps rephrase your answer - so yes you can but you need to find the linux binaries and upload them with your lambda package?

Comment: Yes, being linux it's harder to run exe, maybe convert it to binary. I did not know Lambda can run executables, not being its purpose and for security reasons. Good to know

Comment: Yeah it's a bit funky, personally I'd recommend moving to a t2.micro for customers with this use case rather than Lambda, but saying that if he scrape quick enough it might be OK